# Set data on active slide - Microsoft Office 365

Tags: ms-office, office365, powerpoint, office365api, office-addins

I need help on how to set data on an active slide (read view) on a PowerPoint in an Office 365 add-in. I had thought that the code below which works in an edit view should work in a read view but it returns an *internal error* message.

```
      Office.context.document.getActiveViewAsync(


            function (asyncResult) {

                if (asyncResult.value === 'read') {
                    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync('What I want to write on the active slide');
                }
               else{

                    console.log(asyncResult.value);
                }
            });
              `
```